# raisecom olt (ISCOM5508) default gateway

Tags: fiber

how can i config the default gateway and the mgmt ip address in this raisecom  equipment?

```
Product Name      : ISCOM5508
Product Version   : P300R003C000T000
ROAP Version      : 1.3
System MAC Address: 000e.5e3e.aa7e


Slot ID: 1

Card Type         : ISCOM5508-GPSC

System1  Version  : ISCOM5508-GPSC_ROAP_2.41.1(SP1)_20160503

System2  Version  : ISCOM5508-GPSC_ROAP_2.41.2(SP1)_20161010(active)(committed)

Mainrom1 Version  : ISCOM5508-GPSC_FLASH_MAINROM_2.3.2_20131122(active)(committed)

Mainrom2 Version  : ISCOM5508-GPSC_FLASH_MAINROM_2.3.2_20131122

Bootrom  Version  : ISCOM5508-GPSC_FLASH_BOOTROM_2.3.1_20131017

Hardware Version  : A.00

Firmware Version  : 2.3_build_61_0

CPLD     Version  : V1.0
```

thanks for the help,

best regards,
1m4g1n3

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

`config`
`ip default-gateway <your default gw>`
`management-port ip address <yourip> <yourmask>`

verify:
`show management-port ip`
`ping <gw ip>`

Just read the manual.

Comment: I already read the manual. And there is no ip def gw option in the equipment. Thats why i am confused.  This is what i can do:


Raisecom(config)#ip 

  dhcp     DHCP service

  route    static route

  routing  Enable a routing process

Also no interface ip 0 option.

Comment: Thats strange. I found default gateway configuration from  "ISCOM5508 Configuration Guide (Rel_01)". Put your error message or configuration. It can be help.

Comment: This config guide is not for this equipment, I ve got different card inserted in slot 1. That is why I inserted the version comment. The correct manual is this one: "ISCOM5508-GP (A) Configuration Guide (Rel_02)" I dont have any configuration at all couse i still connecting via console cable and first i want the olt to be reachable from different network.

Comment: GPSC is control module. Does device boot with system_boot image?

Comment: nope. I upgraded via tftp.